# Once I can save this string as image, other time I can'

Tags: python, image-processing

Ok. Long story short.

My camera has a method which takes a photo and this is what it returns:

```
[160, 120, 3, 10, 1287848024, 96181, 'super long image string']
```

I am able to decode the string and save it as image right after I call the method like this:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
  image = camProxy.getImageRemote(nameId)
  imageWidth = image[0]
  imageHeight = image[1]
  imageByteArray = image[6]
  im = Image.fromstring("YCbCr",(imageWidth,imageHeight),imageByteArray)
  fileName = str(time.time())+".jpg"
  im.save(fileName, "JPEG")
```

This works nicely and I can open the saved images.

However, if I just save the string into a txt file and later I want to load it and save as image like this:

```
f = open("rawImage.txt", "r")
data = f.readline()
f.close()

# save as image
im = Image.frombuffer("YCbCr",(160,120),data)
im.save("test.jpg", "JPEG")
```

What I get is almost completely green image.

Here is an example string which I keep having problems with:

http://richardknop.com/rawImage.txt

Here is a complete output of the getImageRemote() method of the camera for that image:

http://richardknop.com/log.txt

Anybody got ideas what could be wrong? Is this some issue related to encoding? All files are saved as ASCII but I have tried saving them all as UTF-8 as well.

EDIT:

How I have written the image to file? I just redirected the output of the script:

```
python script.py > output.txt
```

And in the script I had:

```
print imageByteArray
```

Comment: Why don't you simply save the images as binary data instead?

Comment: Where do you use i inside of your for block?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you save the image to a text file? You may want to base64 encode the data before writing it out as text, if you are not doing so already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working by changing the file mode from `"r"` to `"rb"`.

Here's the working code:

```
import time
import Image
image_data = [160, 120, 3, 10, 1287848024, 96181, 'really long string from http://richardknop.com/log.txt']
imageWidth = image_data[0]
imageHeight = image_data[1]
imageByteArray = image_data[6]
fout = open("image_data.txt", "wb")
fout.write(imageByteArray)
fout.close()
fin = open("image_data.txt", 'rb')
image_string = fin.read()
fin.close()
im = Image.fromstring("YCbCr",(imageWidth,imageHeight),image_string)
fileName = str(time.time())+".jpg"
im.save(fileName, "JPEG")
```

I verified that you are correct, in that `read` and `readline` make no difference here, but I still advise using `read`, because that says what you mean.

Here's my original answer:

Change `data = f.readline()` to `data = f.read()`.  `read` grabs the whole file, `readline` grabs just one line.

Comment: I think that's not the problem. The text file has just one line. And using read() instead of readline() doesn't help.

Comment: How are you writing the file?

Comment: Please give it a try.  You have binary data.  There is 1 in 256 chance that any single byte will encode to character code 10, a newline.  Given that your data is much longer than 256 characters, you are nearly guaranteed that there are newlines there.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski I changed "r" to "rb" and readline to read and I still get the green image. It is supposed to be an image of a room. Did you get the correct image saved on the disk?

Comment: yes, it's very blurry.  looks like a large desk in the middle with some items stacked on it.  Perhaps you can paste the code where you write the image to file.

Comment: I have added how I saved the image string to file. I have several images saved in txt files like this. Could you also post the code you got working? Because my code generates just a totally green picture (there is no desk, nothing, just green image).

Comment: The photo is blurry because I used YUV color space to save as much data as possible. I want to create a live video stream from images from the camera installed on a robot and it has to be fast. The resolution will be greater though. I use tiny images like this just for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should read and write into your file using binary mode like this :

```
open('file_name', 'wb')
open('file_name', 'rb')
```

Answer (score 1):

Read in the data:

```
import Image
import ast

with open('rawImage.txt','r') as f:
   raw_data=f.read()
with open('log.txt','r') as f:
   log_data=f.read()   
log_data=ast.literal_eval(log_data)
imageWidth=log_data[0]
imageHeight=log_data[1]
log_data=log_data[6]
```

Let's try to see if `raw_data` (from rawImage.txt) is the same string as 
`log_data` (from log.txt). Oops: they're not the same length:

```
print(len(raw_data))
# 146843
print(len(log_data))
# 57600
```

Take a peek at the beginning of both strings. It appears `raw_data` has written 4 characters for '\x81' when a single character `\x81` was intended.

```
print(list(raw_data[:10]))
# ['6', '}', '\\', 'x', '8', '1', '8', '}', '\\', 'x']
print(list(log_data[:10]))
# ['6', '}', '\x81', '8', '}', '\x81', '7', '\x90', '\x8a', '4']
```

This might have happened because rawImage.txt was opened in writing mode `'w'` instead of `'wb'`. The best solution is to write rawImage.txt using the right writing mode, as [Steven Rumbalski does here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017609/once-i-can-save-this-string-as-image-other-time-i-can/4017629#4017629).

But given this predicament, here is a way you can fix it:

```
raw_data_fixed=raw_data.decode('string_escape')
```

Now this works:

```
im = Image.fromstring("YCbCr",(imageWidth,imageHeight),raw_data_fixed)
im.show()
```